# Java Android add OnScrollChangeListener

Tags: java, android, webview, scroll, overriding

I was trying to add a OnScrollChangeListener to a Custom Webview I am developing. But it won't compile. Following Code I am using:

```
    // Set custom OnScrollChangeListener
    setOnScrollChangeListener(new OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(Webview view, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            isScrolling = true;
            isScrolledToTheTop = (scrollY == 0);
        }
    });
```

But when compiling I got following Errors which makes no sense to me:

```
/.../VEMAWebview.java:36: error: <anonymous de.X.Y.VEMAWebview$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onScrollChange(View,int,int,int,int) in OnScrollChangeListener
        setOnScrollChangeListener(new OnScrollChangeListener() {
                                                               ^
/.../VEMAWebview.java:37: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
            @Override
            ^
```

where above mentioned onScrollChange Funktion is in Line 37.

Basically it's saying that the onScrollChange was not overridden.
and in the next line it says the @override is not allowed because it is not overriding any function

How can I solve this ?

Comment: The method onScrollChange takes View as it's first argument. You are passing Webview. In the case of overriding, method signature must be same. Change it as:
@Override
        public void onScrollChange(View view, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            isScrolling = true;
            isScrolledToTheTop = (scrollY == 0);
        }

Answer (score 0):

It was the wrong signatur as Thug Life suggested in the Comment.

The correct code should be like this:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;

...

    // Set custom OnScrollChangeListener
setOnScrollChangeListener(new OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(View view, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        isScrolling = true;
        isScrolledToTheTop = (scrollY == 0);
    }
});
```

I don't want to ask why Java not just said the signature does not match any available supertype method. I am glad that my project is C++ based (C++ simply tells you about a not matching signature) and that I did only need this little Java snipped.